# Converting randomly generated list of numbers into integers

Tags: python, list, integer

```
elif a == "other":
    numbers = [randrange(33, 126) for _ in range(8)]
    for n in numbers:
        print(n)
        print(chr(n))
    sum(numbers)
    numbercomp = numbers /8 -32
```

I am trying to convert the list of numbers that are randomly generated into a  integer so I can divide them by 8 and minus 32.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I believe you just need to store the result of sum -- `numbers = sum(numbers)`

Comment: What you're asking isn't possible. You're asking to convert a list into an integer. Just with that descripcion, there's no solution.

Comment: Okay, so I have added the numbers = sum(numbers) and it appears to have worked! however. i'm encountering a problem with my cipher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you want to generate 8 random numbers from the range 33-126. Then sum up the numbers and divide by 8. Then you want to subtract 32 from it.

You generated the list of numbers alright. You just need to store the sum in a variable and later use it. I would do it like this:

```
numbers = [randrange(33, 126) for _ in range(8)]
num_sum = sum(numbers)
numbercomp = (num_sum/8) - 32
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want a list of integers with the given transformation.  This would be faster using the **map** function, but I expect this is easier to grasp.  I'm worried about the transformation, since it guarantees negative numbers -- a curious result for most applications.

```
from random import randrange
numbers = [randrange(33, 126) for _ in range(8)]
for n in numbers:
    print(n)
    print(chr(n))
sum(numbers)
numbercomp = [int(_)/8 - 32 for _ in numbers]
print numbercomp
```

Sample output:

```
121
y
80
P
79
O
70
F
54
6
98
b
82
R
125
}
[-17, -22, -23, -24, -26, -20, -22, -17]
```